# A question on the FEM method

Tags: finite-element-method

In the Finite element, we take a function with free parameters and put it into an equation, but it doesn't solve this equation, so why don't we get $0=1$?

Why does this method give an approximate solution?

If I have the equation $2*f(x)^2=x$, and put in $f(x)=ax+b$ into it, I get $0=1$, not a good approximation, so why does this method give a good approximation?

Answer (score 0):

Your description of FEM looks much simpler than I can remember. :)

A characteristic property is that the domain of the sought solution is divided into parts, the finite elements, and that on each element an approximation is sought.

So I see that you intend to you use linear functions as approximations, but what is the finite element you are working on? I would expect at least one $I \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Then out of the infinite many linear functions characterized by $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, according to what criteria will you select the best fit?

Here are two continuous functions which would solve your equation:

[image]

You see that the choice of the best linear approximation depends on the interval you want to approximate on.

Comment: [0,1]..................